# Jquery datepicker and Spring Locale. Change datepicker language with locale language. How to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, datepicker

Good day people.Thank you that you are on that amazing web-resource helping people with literally anything.

So, I have NO experience in JQuery and JavaScript at all. I got from internet the simple JQuery datepicker code:

```
$("#dateinput").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    beforeShowDay: beforeShowDayHandler,
    showOn: 'both',
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", false);
    },
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    }
});

function beforeShowDayHandler(date) {
    if (self.SelectedDayValue != -1) {
        if (date.getDate() != 1) {
            return [false, '', 'selected'];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
}
```

I have an idea to affect on my datepicker to change his locale when my Springs locale changed. Here is my spring locale config :

In my Servlet-context.xml:

```
<!-- Change my local over url variable lang. Example: ?lang=en -->
    <interceptors>
        <beans:bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
             <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
        </beans:bean>
    </interceptors>

    <!-- Fething lacale from use cookie files -->
    <beans:bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="ru"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

In my jsp peace of code witch change locale of page when user click link:

```
Language/Язык/文 : <a href="input?lang=en">English</a>||<a href="input?lang=ru">Русский</a>||<a href="input?lang=cn">中文</a>
```

As you can see when user press CHANGE LANGUAGE LINK it passing some parameters in address string in browser like: `localhost:8080/controller/main.jsp?lang=en`

How can I take this one parameter and put it to my datepicker code??? Any example?? And thank you anyway to you all if you want be able to help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code snippet in a project once. Hope it helps:

```
$(function() {
    calendar();
});

function calendar(){
   //omitted datepicker init 

   $(".calendar").datepicker("option", $.datepicker.regional["<%=locale%>"]);
}
```

All date field's css attributes are specified as calender and locale is retrieve in java code. I'm not familiar with CookieLocaleResolver, I used SessionLocalResolver but there should be equivalent way to get the Locale.

```
public static Locale getLocaleFrom(HttpSession session) {
    return (Locale) session
            .getAttribute(SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
}
```

And I remember we modified the datepicker for different locale values between Java and datepicker. You could use a mapping mechanism as an alternative solution.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your reply. It seems like very good solution. I'm nor familiar with Jquery and can't tell that I totally understand, but any way thank you.